# Threejs blender exporter exports in wrong format

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

I'm trying to export a blender model to threejs json with the help of the provided [blender exporter](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/tree/master/utils/exporters/blender). On parsing the json file I get an error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined
```

The json file looks as following (ommiting vertices and faces):

```
{
    "textures": [],
    "metadata": {
        "version": 4.3,
        "sourceFile": "UV-World.blend",
        "type": "Object",
        "generator": "io_three"
    },
    "images": [],
    "materials": [],
    "object": {
        "matrix": [1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,1],
        "children": [{
            "type": "Mesh",
            "name": "Kugel",
            "uuid": "5051D840-9982-4F9A-8CFF-36303B38E091",
            "position": [0.0,0.0,0.0],
            "rotation": [-1.5707964897155762,0.0,0.0],
            "scale": [1.0,0.9999999403953552,0.9999999403953552],
            "visible": true,
            "castShadow": true,
            "receiveShadow": true,
            "geometry": "DEAE2CE2-9824-4F91-BE4C-1C80BEDC566A"
        }],
        "type": "Scene",
        "uuid": "8C543616-2AB0-4D1D-B76D-549E32A0E468"
    },
    "geometries": [{
        "type": "Geometry",
        "data": {
            "name": "KugelGeometry",
            "metadata": {
                "version": 3,
                "faces": 512,
                "vertices": 482,
                "generator": "io_three"
            },
            "vertices": [...],
            "faces": [...]
        },
        "uuid": "DEAE2CE2-9824-4F91-BE4C-1C80BEDC566A"
    }]
}
```

This seems to be not in the [format that threejs expects](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3) it to be. If I manually change the json to be the following threejs parses and displays the model as expected.

```
{
    "scale": 1,
    "vertices": [...],
    "faces": [...]
}
```

Exporting and importing to/from obj works as expected.

As I could not find anyone also having this problem, I guess it's a usage error. I'm new to blender, so maybe I did something wrong there? I'm using Blender 2.73a and threejs just cloned from the repository.

Comment: Show us your loading code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I suspect you are using `JSONLoader`. Try using `ObjectLoader` instead.

Comment: Is `JSONLoader` only for [format version 3](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3), while `ObjectLoader` being version 4?

Comment: @syntonym that is correct! the next version should throw a console error about this.

Comment: Here is the complete code for loading using ObjectLoader.

    var loader = new THREE.ObjectLoader();

    loader.load('models.json', function( obj ){
        console.log(obj);
        scene.add( obj );
    });

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use JSONLoader, uncheck *scene* option. then, you will have a single mesh JSON file, you expect.

[image]

Comment: It was old version of the Blender Exporter. not Clara.io.
If you use Blender, just use newest one and uncheck all of scene items.